# Huawei phone showing a biometric problem when using gallery

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I am opening the gallery from code to select a photo and when going back to my app I get the following error:

```
2020-05-24 13:06:41.408 1767-1767/? E/AuthenticationService: Failed to get biometric interface NoSuchElementException: 
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at android.os.HwBinder.getService(Native Method)
        at android.os.HwBinder.getService(HwBinder.java:91)
        at vendor.huawei.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint.V2_1.IExtBiometricsFingerprint.getService(IExtBiometricsFingerprint.java:48)
        at vendor.huawei.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint.V2_1.IExtBiometricsFingerprint.getService(IExtBiometricsFingerprint.java:52)
        at com.huawei.systemserver.securitymgr.AuthenticationServiceImpl.getFingerprintDaemonEx(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1483)
        at com.huawei.systemserver.securitymgr.AuthenticationServiceImpl.sendCmdToHal(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1502)
        at com.huawei.systemserver.securitymgr.AuthenticationServiceImpl.se_native_NavigationAFDDFDSwitch(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1344)
        at com.huawei.systemserver.securitymgr.AuthenticationServiceImpl.switchAFDDFD(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1453)
        at com.huawei.systemserver.securitymgr.AuthenticationServiceImpl.access$700(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:59)
        at com.huawei.systemserver.securitymgr.AuthenticationServiceImpl$SettingsObserver.onChange(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1394)
        at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:130)
        at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:145)
        at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:216)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
2020-05-24 13:06:41.408 1767-1767/? W/AuthenticationService: fingerprint HIDL not available
2020-05-24 13:06:41.409 1767-1767/? E/AuthenticationService: Fingerprintd is not available!
```

Do you have any idea on the possible cause?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So apparently the problem was not the root cause but a (confusing) consequence of the original error which was caused by the way I tried to open the photo gallery, copy pasting some other snippet from google solved the issue.

Comment: Providing the copy/pasta snippet that was in error could be helpful to others that come across this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the hidl process.
Please check that whether your phone supports fingerprint recognition or not.

Comment: Thanks for trying... seems like it was a derived error unrelated to the real cause.